# Geojson Incomplete Rendering in JsFiddle for Highmaps Useage

Tags: javascript, jquery, highmaps

I am interested in creating maps of local voter districts, that can be usable in Highmaps. I am loading the maps in JsFiddle as noted in the HighCharts Custom Geojson Maps help section.

I am struggling to get my geojson map of the local State Assembly District into a format that will generate a Highmap map. I checked my geojson code in a test boiler on JsFiddle (please see below for image), and it worked exactly as I wanted it too, however when I create a fiddle to generate the map, a blank image is generated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My dashboard with the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/mboghossian/u9w4qtec/).

Geojson Boiler Tester Output:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
height: 500px; 
width: 500px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
 margin-top: 10em;
 text-align: center;
 color: gray;
}
```

**JavaScript**

Code too long for stackoverflow to properly load, please see dashboard for code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You have several errors:*

1. **You must include jQuery** in the left "Frameworks & Extensions".
2. The json code have **syntax errors**! Use **jsLint** or **jsHint** to see them.
3. The expected format of the **"series" object is wrong** too! It expects the metadata inside a **"metaData" attribute**.

Check out your code now, but working ;)  --> [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/FacuCode/xheLmLgL/)

```
$(function () {
    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        series : [{
            mapData: { // <-- HERE IS THE METADATA ATTRIBUTE!
                "type":"FeatureCollection",
                .....                 
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

I hope this can help you!!

Comment: Thank you Facundo; I'll make sure I check my code with jsLint and make sure the format of the object is correct for my next series of maps. :)